# Очень долгая компиляция пары строк кода в Go

Tags: golang, компиляция

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("wdw")
}
```

На моей машине OS win 10 код компилируется секунд 10! При том, что почти любые мои проекта на Ubuntu компилируются фактически мгновенно. Друзья в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: антивирус. Ищите и отключайте. И только не говорите, что его у Вас нет - он есть.

Comment: Если на win 10 есть по умолчанию, то есть.

Comment: пробуйте отключить. Также убедитесь, что ничего другого не кушает память. К примеру, если есть google chrome, открыто 20-30 вкладок, а памяти 4 гига, то будет свопится и будет тупить.

Comment: Не знаю, в этом ли дело, но Windows вообще в среднем медленнее, особенно работа с файлами. У коллеги ветки в Гите переключаются по несколько секунд.

Comment: проверил у себя компиляцию. Первая за 3 секунды, последующие за 0.16. Думаю, проблема в том, что винде нужно закешировать компилятор и все его добро.

Comment: Отключени антивируса и всего сопутствующего добра не дало результатов. Решил проблему установкой Ubuntu)